# PHP - call ASP.Net MVC action

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I don't know nothing about PHP and required me to call from PHP an ASP.Net MVC page to integrate on the PHP page.

I thought using a ajax call will work and be easier to implement. But it seems not to work.

**My code:**

```
<div class="pageContainer">    
    <?php   
        echo 'start debugging';

        $param1=$_GET['param1'];
        $param2=$_GET['param2'];
        $htmlPage = '';

        $parameters = {
            myParam1: $param1,
            myParam2: $param2
        };

        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyController/MyAction',
                data: $parameters,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                processdata: true,
                success: function(result){
                    try {
                        $htmlPage = result->HtmlReturned;
                    }
                    catch (er) {
                        alert('Error');
                        return false;
                    }               
                },
                async: true,
                crossDomain: false,
                error: function(er){ alert('Error'); }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            echo 'catch';
            alert('Error');
        }

        echo $htmlPage;
    ?>          
</div>
```

What is wrong? I can't usu AJAX calls? I don't get any error and I can't even debug so I don't know what is wrong. My page simply be all empty, without headers without nothing.

The PHP project isn't mine so I can't include any extension or something like that.

Comment: `dataType: 'json',` specifies that the ajax call required the response to be json, yet your saying it returns a view (html). That alone would throw an error.

Comment: omg.. you just mix javascript-code with php-code... it won't work in any case even if you locate this into asp.net page.. do you mix asp.net code with javascript code like this?!

Comment: Maybe if you wrapped your javascript code in a `<script>` tag it would be understood as javascript by your browser. Currently it is not being interpreted as javascript

Comment: nope, it wont, if you do this that way... php cant run javascript code , you need clearly separate different kind of code/language

Comment: @RiggsFolly I understand. But how can I access to the properties `param1` and `param2` on the `$_GET['param1']` and `$_GET['param2']` in javascript?

Comment: @Ninita like any other language used at backend on the server, php / python / perl / ruby / .net / etc - all of them receives a text, parsed it, processing and send a text that your browser can understand and/or execute as javascript code... is your code understandable for php? and for browser? ... I guess not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @RiggsFoly said currently my ajax call wasn't being interpreted as javascript. So I transformed my code to fully JS code and wrapped it in a `<script>` tag.

I don't know how, I can access in JS to `param1` and `param2` variables in `$_GET['param1']` and `$_GET['param2']`.

So, now my code is much clearer and working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {           
        var parameters = {
            myParam1: param1,
            myParam2: param2
        };

        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyController/MyAction',
                data: parameters,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                processdata: true,
                success: function(result){
                    try {
                        $(".pageContainer").html(result.HtmlReturned);
                    }
                    catch (er) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }               
                },
                async: true,
                crossDomain: false,
                error: function(er){ alert('Error'); }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="pageContainer">        
</div>
```